# How can I run my Rails application in a non-root context?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I'm working in a non-privileged environment, and my Rails application's root url is `http://foo.com/bar`.

What is the simplest way to tell Rails that, for example, my stylesheets are in `/bar/stylesheets`, not `/stylesheets`, and make `model_url` point to `/bar/model/baz` instead of `/model/baz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the way you are running the application to that specific path (be it `script/server --path=/sub-uri` or have [deployed passenger to a directory](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri)) you don't need to change the code as the url helpers will automatically adjust their path to the environment.