# How to strip path from all incoming requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a rails 4 application that is going to be deployed to a server with passenger, on '/hello' I have a "hello world" message.

The hosting provider adds a path to all requests to my application, so instead of '/hello' I receive a HTTP GET request with '/app_name/hello'.

How can I strip /app_name from all incoming requests?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

In a previous application I had in sinatra I did this:

```
before do
  request.path_info.gsub!('/app_name', '')
end
```

What's the equivalent in Rails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315868/how-can-i-run-my-rails-application-in-a-non-root-context